# Why it is always redirecting to /login page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I´m learning Spring Boot and having some issues. `http://localhost:8080/login` is the default page of my application but I noticed that when I change to `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://localhost:8080/register`, I always get directed to `/login`.

I already tried solving this problem with a security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return passwordEncoder;
    }
}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```java
package Login;

import org.apache.catalina.User;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@RestController
public class LoginController {
    private final LoginRepository loginRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder; // PasswordEncoder zur Passwortverschlüsselung

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    public LoginController(LoginRepository loginRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.loginRepository = loginRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody UserLogin user){
        logger.debug("Received registration request for user: {}", user.getUsername());
        UserLogin existingUser = loginRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if(existingUser != null){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Benutzername existiert bereits!");
        }
        else{
            String encryptedPW = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
            user.setPassword(encryptedPW);
            loginRepository.save(user);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Benutzer wurde erfolgreich erstellt!");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> newLogin(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) {
        UserLogin user = loginRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user != null && passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Du bist eingeloggt!");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Ungültige Anmeldeinformationen");
        }
    }
}
```

I have also created HTML files with Thymeleaf, where I used `POST` method and right direction.  What is causing this problem?

The log reports say:

For `/register` and `/login`:

There has been a failed authorization attempt for the request to `/register` and `/login`.

The `FilterSecurityInterceptor` reports that the authorization has failed, indicating that the request came from an unauthenticated user.
Subsequently, the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` is executed, redirecting the request to the login page `/login`.

For `/favicon.ico`:

Similar to `/register` and `/login`, a failed authorization attempt is reported here as well.

The `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` redirects the request back to the login page `/login`.

Comment: `.formLogin().loginPage("/login")` will allow anyone to get to your login page, but it won't allow post requests to `/login`, if that's what you're trying to accomplish.  If you're following a tutorial on Spring Boot, I'd also recommend that you find one that's written for the latest version; most of what you have here has been deprecated for quite a while.

Comment: Remove `newLogin` method, Spring Security is doing it. Remove `.loginPage("/login")`. It is the default. You only need it, if you want to customize your login page. You can't call `/register` without a CSRF token. Do your register page submit a CSRF token?

Comment: Removing .formLogin().loginPage("/login") is not solving the problem. And yeah, it does generate a CSRF-token.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable csrf

```
 http.csrf().disable()
```

Or ignore register path

```
 http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/register","/login")
```

Comment: tried both but not working :/